# WWW subdomain not resolving, but domain itself does

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, web, virtualhost

I've spun up a Droplet on DigitalOcean, and I'm in the process of building a site for a local client. I'm using virtualhosts on this droplet since these sites will never see that much traffic, so the server won't ever be under any real load.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with a LAMP environment. I'm using Apache2.

**Website:** http://troy-alabama.com/

When you try to visit www.troy-alabama.com, it doesn't resolve. Here's what my apache2.conf file looks like:

**APACHE2.CONF**

```
# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/taylordaughtry.com/public_html
ServerName www.taylordaughtry.com
ServerAlias taylordaughtry.com

# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/troy-alabama.com/public_html
ServerName www.troy-alabama.com
ServerAlias troy-alabama.com

</VirtualHost>

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

**DNS SETTINGS**

This is what I have set for this domain's DNS. The droplet's name is taylordaughtry.com; I'm not sure if that matters for vhosts?

Here's a screenshot of the Digital Ocean page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2xnc.png

Comment: www.troy-alabama.com works fine on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

So when you get an error of "Failed to Resolve" that means there is a problem with the domain itself. In this case, take where it says "Troy-Alabama" for the first two - You set that up wrong. First, no period at the end. Secondly, its best to have it point to your A, which is @. So your second and third fields where it currently has your domain name, replace those with @.